# Roots of my new Phalaenopsis orchid are yellow, is it mold?

Tags: plant-health, watering, transplanting, orchids

I got a beautiful blooming Phalaenopsis orchid as a gift last week (store-bought). This is my first ever orchid. I looked at some videos about care and replanting and I am concerned that my orchid is not thriving.

Since I got it, it was kept in the clear pot on a tray, and placed in front of a window, but not in direct sunlight. It was not watered at all. The window is opened a couple times a day.

My first concern is a white dust or spiderweb on top of the soil. It looks the closest to mold, but I didn't find anything similar online, and I also heard that some types of mold are beneficial for orchids.

[image: Top of the pot with white clouds/cobwebs]

My second concern is about watering the orchid. A tutorial for beginners suggested to put a skewer in the pot, and only water the orchid (by submerging the pot in water and letting it drip) when the skewer is completely dry. This should happen about once a week, but my skewer is still wet. That's when I noticed that the roots at the bottom of the pot are green-yellow or white, which seemed wrong. The roots are also partially flat and curved to perfectly fit in the packed pot.

I have removed the orchid from the pot, and placed it in a larger bowl to examine the roots and let it dry. It still holds the shape of the pot firmly, and the bottom 2cm/inch of the "dirt" seem somewhat moist to the touch. Most of the roots are firm, but some roots at the bottom of the pot are soft and "deflated".

[image: Wet skewer and roots without the pot]

Are the two issues related? What should I do to hopefully keep the orchid thriving in the long run? I do not have any specialized fertilizer or equipment at hand and will not be able to buy any quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Often the plastic pots orchids are in when sold do not have drainage holes . I believe the plan is the grower waters them ,then they do not need water for weeks or months while sitting in a shop; often a grocery store where plant care is not the clerks main job. When I buy an orchid at a grocery store ,the first thing I do is discard the pot and replant in a pot with several holes for air circulation.

Comment: The pot mine came in had small holes at the bottom, like regular flower pots have. There were no holes on the sides. I saw people were putting their orchids on a mesh to allow air circulation below the pot, so I did that, too